# defining application variable first as undefined in js in global scope

Tags: javascript

I've found this snippet of code inside js file

```
var myApp = undefined;
(function () {
    'use strict';

    if (!window.myApp) {
        window.myApp = {};
    }
    myApp = window.myApp;
    ...

})();
```

is this usual way to define application variable? Why is myApp first defined as undefined?

Comment: No good reason I can see.

Comment: neither do I...

Comment: Well if that script is included after some other script that declares and initializes `myApp`, the code as written guarantees that this script will overwrite the value. It's not the way *I* would do that, but it would work.

Comment: It may add intent of use, possible taken by clarity as some. I would have written: `window.myApp = undefined` to be very explicit if that is the intent. Also, `myApp = window.myApp` seems .. fishy which makes me wonder if the author was misguided about `var` and local-global variable rules. In a non-global context or if the `var` was *inside* the function..